Can you recommend any good researches on the period of Japanese colonization of Taiwan?
Just as the title says, I'm currently looking forward towards learning more about the topic. If you know any works that you find fundamental in a way on this topic, I'll gladly accept any suggestions!
The works can be in both English and Japanese, whichever is fine!
Thank you!

Have you started with the Wikipedia page on Taiwan under Japanese rule? That seems to contain a fairly long list of sources and further reading.

We discourage reference requests as they generate more discussion than answers.  Could you revise to a question that would be answered suggested references?

I like Modern East Asia: An Integrated History. Authors:Jonathan N. Lipman, Barbara A. Molony, Michael A. Robinson

Voting to close for the reasons others have explained.

I’m voting to close this question because we discourage reference requests.
